# Fetch a user's last message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to fetch the last message from a particular user.
The user should be able to say the command and the id of the user to get the last message of, then the bot should send back `message.content` or `message.embed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`lastMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=lastMessage) property of a `User` and use it similar to this...

```js
/*
 * within an async function,
 * inside command code,
 * assuming 'args' is an array of arguments
*/

try {
  const user = await client.fetchUser(args[1]);
  if (!user) return message.channel.send('Oh no, invalid user ID.');

  const lastMessage = user.lastMessage;
  if (!lastMessage) return message.channel.send('No messages from this user found.');

  message.channel.send({lastMessage.content, lastMessage.embed, lastMessage.attachments});
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: @Soham saha you should approve this answer